# Regex to find capitalized words and code string?

Tags: regex

I'm looking to change a simple dash to an em dash in some obituaries we receive.  But it's only after the City of Death where that em dash should go.

The text looks like this:

```
@M_DeathNoticeHed:Alex <\n>Ornelas
@M_DeathNoticeBod:ALAMO <\!-> Alex  Ornelas <\n>, 25,  died Tuesday,  Aug. <\n>16, 2016 at Alamo.  Me<\h>morial Funeral Home of  <\n>San Juan is in charge of ar<\h>rangements.

@M_DeathNoticeHed:Almaquire Cadena
@M_DeathNoticeBod:RIO GRANDE CITY <\!-> Almaquire  <\n>Cadena , 87,  died Tues<\h>day,  Aug. 16, 2016 at Pax <\n>Villa Hospice, in McAllen, <\n>TX.  Sanchez Funeral Home <\n> of  Rio Grande City is in <\n>charge of arrangements.

@M_DeathNoticeHed:AnaRose <\n>Collazi
@M_DeathNoticeBod:MISSION <\!-> AnaRose  <\n>Collazo , 44,  died Wednes<\h>day,  Aug. 17, 2016 at Mis<\h>sion Regional Medical Cen<\h>ter in Mission.  Virgil Wilson <\n>Mortuary of  Mission is in <\n>charge of arrangements.

@M_DeathNoticeHed:Andy Garza
@M_DeathNoticeBod:RIO GRANDE CITY <\!-> Andy  <\n>Garza , 21,  died Tuesday,  <\n>Aug. 16, 2016 at Chicago, <\n>IL.  Rodriguez Funeral <\n>Home of  Roma is in <\n>charge of arrangements.
```

Notice that after every `"@M_DeathNoticeBod: CITY"` is `"<\!->"` which symbolizes the dash that I need changed to an em dash.

My regex code is not getting the `"<\!->"` selected along with the preceding city and `"@M_DeathNoticeHed:"`.

```
@M_DeathNoticeBod:([^A-Za-z]*?[A-Z][A-Za-z]*)([^A-Za-z]*?[A-Z][A-Za-z]*) [<\!->]
```

It is also not selecting cities with 3 names in it like `"RIO GRANDE CITY"`.  I'm selecting this because the dash appears in other spots in the file that I do not want replaced.

If I can select that section I can replace the dash here.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the "<\!->" you want to replace will be the first occurrence after "@M_DeathNoticeBod"?

Comment: It seems there's only one `"<\!->"` for each `"@M_DeathNoticeBod:"`. So why not just search and replace `"<\!->"`?

Comment: Yes that would be the only time I'd want it changed.

Comment: @akinuri because I did not include the full text of the obits many times that code is used elsewhere to represent proper dashes and I can't change those.

Comment: @schnarkle Would [this](https://regex101.com/r/eA1iM9/2) work?

Comment: @akinuri Like a boss!  thanks so much!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lines you care about always start with "@M_DeathNoticeBod:" followed by the city of death, followed by the <!-> you wish to replace, I think something simple would do the job:

`(@M_DeathNoticeBod:.*)<\\!->`

Capture group 1 will contain everything up until that first "<\!->", so you if you're doing a search and replace you can just replace each occurrence of that regex with the contents of group 1 (usually denoted by '\1') followed by an em dash.

Comment: These work great guys, but how do I replace without losing the city name?

Comment: Strangely:

    search:    (@M_DeathNoticeBod:.*)<\\!->
    replace:    \1—

works perfectly in notepad++, but not in TextCrawler Pro where I want it to run as a batch.  It changes nothing in Textcrawler.

Comment: Try using '$1' instead of '\1' in Textcrawler, based on this: https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/textcrawlermanual/regular_expression_reference_guide.htm

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do:

```
@M_DeathNoticeBod:([A-Z ]*) (<\\!->)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are actually looking for:

```
(?<=@M_DeathNoticeBod:).+<\\!->
```

To explain things, the first portion, `(?<=@M_DeathNoticeBod:)` within the parenthesis is the positive lookbehind that doesn't participate in matching but ensures the trailing portion shall always be preceded by that expression.

I the trailing portion `.+` should capture any city name containing any character sequence followed by your <!-> delimiter, which is captured by `<\\!->` regex.